# Unity c# - move player in direction he's facing (instead global space)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I've got this script for player movement + rotation. The problem is when I turn with my character and then press key for going forward it goes bad way because of global space...
For example, when I turn left then press key for going forward it turn back and goes forward instead of going in the direction my character is facing.
I'm so new in c# and unity. So I'd be glad for any help. Thank you!

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SharkMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody rb;
    float xInput;
    float zInput;
    public float moveSpeed;
    public float rotateSpeed;
    private Vector3 direction;
    private Vector3 fwd;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Pohyb ryby
        xInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal2");
        zInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical2");
       
        direction = new Vector3(xInput, 0.0f, zInput);

        if (direction != Vector3.zero)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(direction), rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        
        rb.MovePosition(transform.position + moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime * direction);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Transform.forward](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html) to get the forward vector of the object. Something like this would work, assuming zInput is your Forward/Backward input.

```
xInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal2");
zInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical2");
       
direction = new Vector3(xInput, 0.0f, 0.0f) + (zInput * transform.forward);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It says: "Vector cannot be converted into float"

Comment: Oops, fixed. That's the general idea - if you want to move the `xInput` across the left-right axis of your player, you can use `transform.right`

Comment: OMG! Thanks a lot! It's working now.. I was finding solution for like 2hours. thanks!!

Comment: Oh wait. I've got some problems with using transform.right this is the new code:                                
direction = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)+ (xInput * transform.right) + (zInput * transform.forward) ; The problem is i can't go backwards, and when i try to rotate without moving. It's moving while rotating

Comment: Instead of `new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)` you can use `Vector3.zero`

Comment: Still cant go backwards :/ <- My character start shaking when I want go backwards

Comment: @azurax I recommend you post a new question for the new problem.

Comment: @NarekDaduryan I recommend you replace your xInput part with ```(xInput * transform.right)``` for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply `xInput` by `transform.right` and `zInput` by `transform.forward` then add them together:

```
xInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal2");
zInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical2");
       
direction = xInput * transform.right + zInput * transform.forward;
```

You should probably also cap the magnitude to be 1 so diagonal movement isn't faster than orthogonal:

```
xInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal2");
zInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical2");
       
direction = xInput * transform.right + zInput * transform.forward;
direction = direction.normalized * Mathf.Min(1f, direction.magnitude);
```